# Mapeamento ManyToMany com coluna adicional

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

No meu projeto de estudo, voltado para controle de partidas de futebol, tenho as seguintes entidades:

Jogador

- Nome;

Partida

- Data de realização;
- Gols pro;
- Gols contra;

Preciso ainda registrar os gols da partida por jogador, o que deve ficar no banco desta forma:

```
 Jogador               PartidaJogador                Partida
(id,nome)   (jogador_id, partida_id, numeroGols)  (id,data...)
```

Abaixo as classes já criadas:

```
@Entity
public class Jogador implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String nome;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nome;
    }

}

@Entity
public class Partida implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)    
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String adversario;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDate dataRealizacao;

    @Min(0)
    @NotNull
    private Integer golsPro;

    @Min(0)
    @NotNull
    private Integer golsContra;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<PartidaJogador> jogadoresGols = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAdversario() {
        return adversario;
    }

    public void setAdversario(String adversario) {
        this.adversario = adversario;
    }

    public LocalDate getDataRealizacao() {
        return dataRealizacao;
    }

    public void setDataRealizacao(LocalDate dataRealizacao) {
        this.dataRealizacao = dataRealizacao;
    }

    public Integer getGolsPro() {
        return golsPro;
    }

    public void setGolsPro(Integer golsPro) {
        this.golsPro = golsPro;
    }

    public Integer getGolsContra() {
        return golsContra;
    }

    public void setGolsContra(Integer golsContra) {
        this.golsContra = golsContra;
    }

    public Set<PartidaJogador> getJogadoresGols() {
        return jogadoresGols;
    }

    public void setJogadoresGols(Set<PartidaJogador> jogadoresGols) {
        this.jogadoresGols = jogadoresGols;
    }


}
```

O fluxo básico deve ser a criação de partidas, então preciso dar um save no objeto Partida e assim salvar a entidade relacionada PartidaJogador também.

**Como mapear a tabela `PartidaJogador` com a coluna extra `numeroGols`?**

Comment: Que tal postar o código da classe *PartidaJogador*?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar uma entidade `PartidaJogador` com uma chave primária composta que referencie as chaves das entidades `Partida` e `Jogador`. Exemplo:

#### Altera o relacionamento na tabela `Partida` para:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy="partida")
private Set<PartidaJogador> jogadoresGols = new HashSet<>();
```

#### PartidaJogadorPK

```
@Embeddable
public class PartidaJogadorPK implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long jogadorId;

    private long partidaId;

    public PartidaJogadorPK() {}

    public final void setJogadorId(long jogadorId) {
        this.jogadorId = jogadorId;
    }

    public final void setPartidaId(long partidaId) {
        this.partidaId = partidaId;
    }

    public final long getJogadorId() {
        return jogadorId;
    }

    public final long getPartidaId() {
        return partidaId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (jogadorId ^ (jogadorId >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + (int) (partidaId ^ (partidaId >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof PartidaJogadorPK))
            return false;
        PartidaJogadorPK other = (PartidaJogadorPK) obj;
        if (jogadorId != other.jogadorId)
            return false;
        if (partidaId != other.partidaId)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### PartidaJogador

```
@Entity
public class PartidaJogador {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PartidaJogadorPK pk = new PartidaJogadorPK();


    @MapsId("partidaId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="partidaId", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Partida partida;


    @MapsId("jogadorId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="jogadorId", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Jogador jogador;

    private int numeroDeGols;

    public final Partida getPartida() {
        return partida;
    }

    public final void setPartida(Partida partida) {
        this.partida = partida;
    }

    public final Jogador getJogador() {
        return jogador;
    }

    public final void setJogador(Jogador jogador) {
        this.jogador = jogador;
    }

    public final int getNumeroDeGols() {
        return numeroDeGols;
    }

    public final void setNumeroDeGols(int numeroDeGols) {
        this.numeroDeGols = numeroDeGols;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((pk == null) ? 0 : pk.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof PartidaJogador))
            return false;
        PartidaJogador other = (PartidaJogador) obj;
        if (pk == null) {
            if (other.pk != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!pk.equals(other.pk))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Exemplo de uso:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();

Jogador jogador = new Jogador();
jogador.setNome("Presunto");
em.persist(jogador);


Partida partida = new Partida();
partida.setAdversario("Tabajara");
partida.setDataRealizacao(LocalDate.now());
partida.setGolsPro(3);
partida.setGolsContra(2);

em.persist(partida);

PartidaJogador partidaJogador = new PartidaJogador();
partidaJogador.setJogador(jogador);
partidaJogador.setPartida(partida);
partidaJogador.setNumeroDeGols(2);

//em.persist(partidaJogador);

Set<PartidaJogador> partidaJogadores = new HashSet<>();
partidaJogadores.add(partidaJogador);

partida.setJogadoresGols(partidaJogadores);

em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Adendo: talvez seja interessante você considerar se o gol também deveria ser tratado como uma entidade, já que ele tem atributos próprios relevantes, como o momento em que foi marcado, autor, autor da assistência, etc.

Comment: Neste caso você tem um problema ao meu ver: está salvando a partida sem a informação dos jogadores. Como coloquei na pergunta, desejo salvar diretamente a partida, com o set de PartidaJogador dentro dela.

Comment: @MurilloGoulart a `Partida` precisa ser salva primeiro, já que na tabela `PartidaJogador` é referenciada  o `id` da `Partida`. Se a `PartidaJogador` fosse salva primeiro, haveria uma inconsistência, já que ela não teria uma `Partida` para referenciar. O que você pode fazer parar "burlar" isso, é utilizar um "CascadeType.PERSIST" no relacionamento na entidade `Partida`. Lembre-se que essa transação deve ser atômica, se uma `Partida` não for persistida, a `PartidaJogador` também não.